# Can I use OpenXmlPowerTools in a Flask App

Tags: c#, flask, web-applications, openxml, openxml-powertools

Is it possible to use a C#/.Net based library like [OpenXmlPowerTools](https://github.com/EricWhiteDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools) in a Flask/Python 3 web-app?

My research tells me that I might be able to via a wrapper? or creating a microservice?

Would like to know your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [pythonnet](http://pythonnet.github.io/). I've created a sample class in C# that references the `OpenXmlPowerTools` and `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` assemblies and provides two methods:

```cs
using OpenXmlPowerTools;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;

namespace CodeSnippets.OpenXmlWrapper
{
    public class OpenXmlPowerToolsWrapper
    {
        public static string GetMainDocumentPart(string path)
        {
            using WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, true);
            return wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.GetXElement().ToString();
        }

        public static string FinishReview(string path)
        {
            using WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, true);

            var settings = new SimplifyMarkupSettings
            {
                AcceptRevisions = true,
                RemoveComments = true
            };

            MarkupSimplifier.SimplifyMarkup(wordDocument, settings);
            return wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.GetXElement().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

The corresponding sample Python client looks like this, noting that `clr` is a module provided by `pythonnet`:

```py
import clr
import shutil

clr.AddReference(
    r"..\CodeSnippets.OpenXmlWrapper\bin\x64\Debug\net471\CodeSnippets.OpenXmlWrapper")

from CodeSnippets.OpenXmlWrapper import OpenXmlPowerToolsWrapper

wrapper = OpenXmlPowerToolsWrapper()

# Display contents before finishing review, showing that the document contains revision markup.
xml_with_revision_markup = wrapper.GetMainDocumentPart("DocumentWithRevisionMarkup.docx")
print("Document before finishing review:\n")
print(xml_with_revision_markup)

# Finish review, removing all revision markup.
print("\nFinishing review ...")
shutil.copyfile("DocumentWithRevisionMarkup.docx", "Result.docx")
xml_without_revision_markup = wrapper.FinishReview("Result.docx")

# Display contents after finishing review, showing that the revision markup was removed.
print("\nDocument after finishing review:\n")
print(xml_without_revision_markup)
```

You'll find the full source code in my [CodeSnippets](https://github.com/ThomasBarnekow/CodeSnippets) GitHub repo. Look at the [CodeSnippets.OpenXmlWrapper](https://github.com/ThomasBarnekow/CodeSnippets/tree/master/CodeSnippets.OpenXmlWrapper) and [CodeSnippets.OpenXmlWrapper.PythonClient](https://github.com/ThomasBarnekow/CodeSnippets/tree/master/CodeSnippets.OpenXmlWrapper.PythonClient) projects.

Depending on your use case, you will also be able to use the OpenXmlPowerTools directly. I just implemented a wrapper to provide a simplified interface.